# Problems in embedding VLC media player in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, media-player, object-tag

I am trying to add or embed VLC media player into my asp.net web page.

```
 the error I am getting is that object tag must contain a class,classid or progid attribute  but  I don't know how to get the values for those attributes.
```

Please help and be free to suggest any other way if possible for any media player that can run MP4 videos.I have
    written the following code in the design

```
  <div>
            <object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
                     autoplay="yes" lop="no"  runat="server" ID="video" 
                     style="width: 452px; height: 278px" />
   <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-D51-BE1D1C159921"                                  codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab"
           height="28"></object>
            </div>
            <div><asp:Button ID="button_play" runat="server" Text="Play" on click="button_play_Click"/>
            </div>

 the error I am getting is that object tag must contain a class,classid or progid attribute but I don't know how to get the values for those attributes.Please help and be free to suggest any other way if possible for any media player that can run MP4 videos.
```